# Checkbox button does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a set of checkboxes as Bootstrap buttons, so as to have a different style instead of the traditional checkboxes. Here is the code:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-primary" id="area_selection_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="study_area.a" ng-true-value="'design'" autocomplete="off"/> Design
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary" id="area_selection_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="study_area.b" ng-true-value="'economics'" autocomplete="off"> Economics
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary" id="area_selection_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="study_area.c"  ng-true-value="'management'" autocomplete="off"> Management
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary" id="area_selection_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="study_area.d" ng-true-value="'marketing'" autocomplete="off"> Marketing
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary" id="area_selection_checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="study_area.e" ng-true-value="'software engineering'" autocomplete="off"> Software engineering
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="softskill_filter.e" ng-true-value="'creativity'"/>
            Creativity
        </label>

<tt>value1 = {{study_area}}</tt><br/>
    </div>
```

Note that the only checkbox that isn't classed or has ID is the only one that works...
And the CSS for the buttons:

```
#area_selection_checkbox {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #EDF1F5;
  border-color: #EDF1F5;
  color: #787985;
  font-weight: 500;
  outline: none !important;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border: none;
}


#area_selection_checkbox.active, #area_selection_checkbox:active,
  #area_selection_checkbox.active:hover, #area_selection_checkbox:active:hover{
    background-color: #787985;
    border-color: #787985;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#area_selection_checkbox:hover, #area_selection_checkbox:focus {
  background-color: #E1E6ED;
  border-color: #E1E6ED;
  color: #787985;
}
```

The thing is, when I click the buttons, the `ng-model` does not update, like the checkbox wasn't even there. 
I even have the code for the `ng-model` on my page, but it does nothing:

```
 <tt>value1 = {{study_area}}</tt><br/>
```

Am I missing something here. Btw, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Thank you.

Comment: You can't use the same id for multiple checkboxes as id is to be unique to the entire document. If they are related use the identifier as a class name or name attribute. Please read the spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: @scrappedcola I've put it in the class name but it the problem remains.

Comment: Rather than showing the css for your checkboxes providing the code for your model would be more helpful as you state the issue is with the model updating?

Comment: @scrappedcola I updated the code in the end. I'm simply printing my model, but it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular directives. Are you loading angular.js? There is no need disable autocomplete on checkboxes - omit that. Have a look at ng-repeat since you are creating duplicate code in your template.

Inside your angular controller have your choices defined

```
this.currentChoice = 'a';
this.availableChoices = [{
        id: 'choice-a',
        label: 'Choice A',
        value: 'a'
    }, {
        id: 'choice-b',
        label: 'Choice B',
        value: 'b'
    }
];
```

Then in your template do something like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" id="{{choice.id}}" ng-repeat="choice in ctrl.availableChoices">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.currentChoice" ng-true-value="'{{choice.value}}'"/> {{choice.label}}
    </label>
</div>
```

I wrote this without testing or knowing which version of angular you are using. Keep in mind that the syntax of angular code changed here and there. But you should get the idea of how to improve your code.

Comment: Please add the angular controller / directive logic to your question if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle that appears to work fine. The only difference is that I have injected angular-ui-bootstrap

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

which looks like what you were trying to do.

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/declanmcd/9bb9v3ug/)

Comment: Yeah your fiddle works, but strangely I already had that injected on my main module...

Comment: It is down to the versions used then. What versions are you using? Post your full code in case there is something else

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.6.1 and Bootstrap 3.3.7
Nonetheless, I removed the `data-toggle="buttons"` and the checkboxes started working, but the tick re-appeared.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to just use angular 1.6.1 and bootstrap 3.3.7 and it all works fine. You still haven't posted your code. Perhaps its something to do with the way you are initialising the angular code? Post your angular code.

Comment: what files do you need?

Comment: the javascript code you are using to initialise the module in angular

Comment: This is the code for the module in which this problem is:

     'use strict';

     var talentforce_company =      angular.module('TalentForce_Application.company',      ['TalentForce_Application']);`

Comment: I've updated the fiddle code with your javascript and it all works fine. I obviously don't have the module 'TalentForce_Application' that you are injecting. So the problem is likely in that module's code. If you posted your javascript code it would be easier to find out why it's not working for you, but the code above is all working in that fiddle example, is it not?

Comment: I have the project as private repo, so it is hard for me to link you. I can show you the main module, though:

http://pastebin.com/vHR6P1tD

Comment: Ok, I see you have a LOT of modules being injected, any one of which can be causing an issue. The only way to fix this is to start with nothing being injected (as in the fiddle), make sure that works, then start injecting the modules one by one. just comment out all the other code and leave something basic (like the fiddle) to ensure it works.
Add in each module one by one and test......see how you get on with that.